# Динамическая память в Win32 api

Tags: c++, winapi

Почему в Win32 не используется динамическая память при создании элементов?

Например, в Qt кнопка создаётся так:

```
QPushButton button = new QPushButton(this);
```

В Win32 делается это так:

```
HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow(...);
```

Это нормально? Стек не перегрузится? Можно ли создавать элементы, используя динамическую память?

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не используется динамическая память?

Comment: Я предполагаю, что не используется. Ведь не используется new. Или я не прав?

Comment: да, ты не прав.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В Win32 объекты интерфейса (окна, кнопки и т.д.) являются системными объектами, т.е., владелец памяти, занятой этими объектами - ОС, а не процесс пользователя.
Поэтому при создании объекта пользователь получает целое число - handle объекта (индекс во внутреннем виндовом массиве всех созданных объектов интерфейса), а не ссылку.  Конечно, там используется динамическая память, но пользователь не видит реальных адресов этих объектов.

Для чего так сделано?  Ну, например, чтобы винда, выполняя работу с этими объектами (напр, перерисовка экрана), не наткнулась на ситуацию, когда пользователь что-то нехорошее с этой памятью сделал (освободил или перезаписал мусором).  То есть, чтобы гарантировать по возможности безошибочную работу подсистемы ГУЙ вне зависимости от багов в гуёвых приложениях. (Нет, в слове "гуёвых" нет опечатки)

Comment: *"владелец памяти, занятой этими объектами - ОС"* А точно? Есть ссылка, где можно про это почитать?

Comment: А что тут непонятного?  Если у тебя нет ссылки на эту память, то владелец - не ты )))

Comment: Я бы скорее поверил, что выделяются они в памяти процесса, который их создает.

Comment: хороший ответ, я дополню что само `API` (не только Win32) предполагает ограничения к ресурсам и низкоуровневому доступу, так как это всего лишь интерфейс взаимодействия для программистов. Не знаю можно ли раздобыть исходник функции `CreateWindow`, но  по исходникам можно узнать что происходит, либо через деассемблирование но это намного сложнее.